# Minimal diffing with golang templates?

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's say I have a page, it a header and a body. In the header are links, and on click the body changes, but the header remains.
To build this with the `html/template` library is easy, but also seems dumb if I just send back a whole new page (fetching the information in the header from the database every time). How to I switch out body templates depending on the `url` I guess.

Here is what I have:

`

```
{{template "GlobalNav"}} 
 {{template "GroupHeader" .Header }} 
 {{ if eq .Active "" }}
 {{ template "GroupBody" .Body }}
 {{ else if eq .Active "papers" }}
 {{ template "GroupPapers" .Body }}
 {{ else if eq .Active "projects" }}
 {{ template "GroupProjects" .Body }}
 {{ end }}`

Server Side:

`http.HandleFunc("/g/", Groups)
http.HandleFunc("/g/papers", GroupsPapers)
http.HandleFunc("/g/projects", GroupsProjects)
func Groups() {
 header := fromDBHeader(id)
body := fromDBMain(id)
render Home template ...
}
func GroupsPapers() {
  header := fromDBHeader(id)
   body := fromDBPapers(id)
   render Paper template ...
   }
func GroupsProjects() {
header := fromDBHeader(id)
body := fromDBProjects(id)
render Project template ...
}
```

`

Is it time for some JS?

Answer (score 0):

try this way put the html files to html folder  add html and js files to it.

```
func webServer() {
http.Handle(
    "/",
    http.StripPrefix(
        "/",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("html")),
    ),
)
http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
```

}

AND BROWSE IT UNDER http://localhost:9000/